# Getting dojo comboBox value

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I have a dojo comboBox. I want to get the value of the comboBox when the content is being changed.

Problem: I only get the previous changed value
Example:

ComboBox: "1234" I get 123
ComboBox: "12345" I get 1234

```
new dijit.form.ComboBox({intermediateChanges: false, propercase: true, autoComplete: false, hasDownArrow: "false", id: "Search", onChange: getValue,
        queryExpr: "*${0}*", /*onBlur:FamilyNameLostFocus,*/ name: "Search", style: "width:100%"}, dojo.byId('TD_PatientSearch'));

function getValue(){
  console.debug(dijit.byId('PatientSearch').getValue(););
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the intermediateChanges: true if you want to use this functionality.

Check out here for further Information : http://davidwalsh.name/dijit-intermediatechanges

regards, Miriam

Comment: Thanks! I've somehow missed that!

Comment: Sometimes you're blind to the simple things;-) I know this too.